# Почему grid контейнер не умещается в основной контейнер с контентом?

Tags: html, css, grid

[image: Есть контент организованный с помощью grid loyaut, на фото мобильная версия]
Как сделать чтобы контент не вылазил за пределы основного (мобильного) контейнера, вот такого:

```
.container{
        max-width: 306px;
        
        overflow-x: hidden;
    }
```

grid контейнер сделан вот так:

```
grid-template-areas: 
        "sub1" 
        "sub2" 
        "sub3"
        "video";
        grid-column-gap: 0px;
        grid-row-gap: 0px;
```

Comment: Зачем вам грид на адаптиве? Тем более, если все друг под другом? Ну и сделайте минимально воспроизводимый пример. Здесь или на jsfiddle условном.

Comment: мало задать ширину родительского контейрера, надо следить за дочерними элементами, их шириной